# nullif when zero or negative value

Tags: switch-statement, netsuite, saved-searches

I frequently use the nullif when value equals to zero, and wondering if it's possible to also display null  when it equals to negative number? My current formula is NULLIF({quantity}-{quantityshiprecv}  ,0) but this displays negative numbers when {quantityshiprecv} is greater than {quantity}, and I'm hoping to display null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify the first argument to return 0 if `{quantity}-{quantityshiprecv}` is negative, but still give the correct answer if it's positve.  Here's one way:

```
NULLIF(({quantity}-{quantityshiprecv} + ABS({quantity}-{quantityshiprecv}))/2,0)
```

This adds the absolute value of the difference to the unchanged difference.  If the difference is positive, that gives you double what you want.  If it's negative the absolute (`ABS()`) will negate that negative value leaving you with zero.  You can then divide by 2; positive is now correct, negative remains zero.  The rest of the `NULLIF()` remains the same.